# what is the difference between function call and reference

Tags: reactjs

what is the difference between function calling and function Referencing

```
onClick={this.clickedbutton()}
```

and function reference

```
onClick={this.clickedbutton}
```

Comment: a function call will execute the function, while a function reference will assign the reference of function to onClick and whenever onClick is called, clickedButton will be called

Comment: Try this: `function foo() { return 42;}; console.log(foo); console.log(foo());`.

Answer (score 2):

The first will be called every time render is done. The second only when there is a click event.

Answer (score 0):

The first function introduces a new anonymous function on every render which may cause performance issue and should be performed when arguments needed. On the other hand the second function is function reference more simpler and efficient and this.clickedbutton is passed directly function reference as click handler which executes when click event occures like on clicking the button.